# Disproving with a counter example when changing which side is the subset

Tags: logic, examples-counterexamples

I originally wanted to know how to disprove by counter example and found out that I was trying to disprove something that was true.

MPW and Brian in the comment section of MPW's answer helped me discover that while it might be true that one side is a subset of the other, the reverse may not be true.

Comment: You won't find a counterexample because the statement is true, not false. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $x\in (A\cap B\cap C)\setminus D$. Then $x\in A$, $x\in B$, $x\in C$, and $x\notin D$.

- Since $x\in B$, certainly $x\in B\cup C$.
- Since $x\in B\cup C$ and $x\notin D$, we know $x\in(B\cup C)\setminus D$.
- Since $x\in A$ and $x\in(B\cup C)\setminus D$, we know $x\in A\cap ((B\cup C)\setminus D)$.

We have just shown that if $$x\in (A\cap B\cap C)\setminus D$$ then $$x\in A\cap ((B\cup C)\setminus D)$$ In other words, we have shown that $(A\cap B\cap C)\setminus D \subseteq 
 A\cap ((B\cup C)\setminus D)$.

So the statement is in fact true. You won't find any counterexample since non exists.

Comment: If the two sides were reversed would there be a counter example?

Comment: @LogicFail: Yes. Notice that if $D=\varnothing$, the two sets in question are $A\cap B\cap C$ and $A\cap(B\cup C)$. It should be pretty easy to find an example in which those two sets are not equal.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks! I will see if I can find the elements to disprove it now.

Comment: @LogicFail: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Drawing a Venn diagram could be an idea. It's a bit difficult with four sets, though. Here is one way (it's easy, but not necessarily pretty, and might technically not be a Venn diagram, but it gets the job done): Draw a Venn diagram for $A,B,C$, then inside each of the eight regions, draw a circle. $D$ is the union of all these circles.

Now you can just check which of the 16 regions are contained in which of your two sets. This is basically the most general setting you can have. If a Venn diagram says that your inclusion is true, then will always be true, as a Venn diagram is an abstract representation of any possible way sets can overlap. If it shows that your inclusion is false, then you have a concrete counterexample right in front of you.